# issue with between epoch function on sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, unix-timestamp

I am working on a query that is looking to take the current time and find the times that are in between 2 different times. These times are being calculated by looking for the `MIN()` `MAX()` values of a column that shows the seconds after midnight and then adding the current dates epoch seconds accounting for the timezone.

When I run the script I get this error

```
SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (misuse of aggregate: MAX())
```

I have narrowed the issue down to this line:

```
AND c_time > trip_start_time AND c_time < trip_end_time
```

Query with where issue

```
SELECT
    agg_st.trip_id,
    trip_start_time,
    trip_end_time
    route_id,
    route_long_name,
    c_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
       st.trip_id as trip_id,
       unixepoch() as c_time,
       MIN(departure_timestamp) + unixepoch('2022-08-04') + 18000 as trip_start_time,
       MAX(departure_timestamp) + unixepoch('2022-08-04') + 18000 as trip_end_time
    FROM stop_times st
        WHERE trip_id NOT IN ('2954445','2954447')
    AND c_time > trip_start_time AND c_time < trip_end_time
    GROUP BY trip_id 
) agg_st
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t.route_id as route_id,
        t.trip_id as trip_id,
        r.route_long_name as route_long_name 
    FROM trips t
    JOIN routes r ON r.route_id = t.route_id 
    WHERE trip_id NOT IN ('2954445','2954447')
    GROUP BY t.route_id, t.trip_id, r.route_long_name
) agg_trips ON agg_trips.trip_id = agg_st.trip_id;
```

Sample Output

```
trip_id|c_time    |trip_start_time|trip_end_time|
-------+----------+---------------+-------------+
2950377|1659704446|     1659638700|   1659640020|
2950378|1659704446|     1659635100|   1659636420|
2950379|1659704446|     1659631500|   1659632820|
2950380|1659704446|     1659607200|   1659608100|
2950381|1659704446|     1659627900|   1659629220|
```

Comment: You do not show input. More importantly, start learning CTEs!

Answer (score 0):

The columns `trip_start_time` and `trip_end_time` are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause, because they are the result of aggregation.

You could only use them in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
  st.trip_id AS trip_id,
  unixepoch() AS c_time,
  MIN(departure_timestamp) + unixepoch('2022-08-04') + 18000 as trip_start_time,
  MAX(departure_timestamp) + unixepoch('2022-08-04') + 18000 as trip_end_time
FROM stop_times st
WHERE trip_id NOT IN ('2954445','2954447')
GROUP BY trip_id
HAVING c_time > trip_start_time AND c_time < trip_end_time
```